# how to install griffon 2.5 with sdkman

Tags: griffon, sdkman

How do you install griffon version 2.5? If I run

```
sdk list griffon
```

it shows me version 1.5 as latest version.

Comment: I am pretty sure they promote using the lazybones template approach - since the project is based on Gradle, you don't need anything else installed (see http://griffon-framework.org/guide/2.6.0/#_getting_started)

Comment: But using the template approach, I can't use intelij's create project feature, can I? I need to specify a griffon library in order to create the project.. @cjstehno

Comment: You just open the generated build.gradle file in IntelliJ and it will recognize it as a Gradle project.

Comment: No, it doesn't recognize it

Comment: Sorry, works every time for me. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Griffon 2.x is not available as an `sdk` candidate because it no longer has a command line of its own. You either use `gradle` or `maven` to build Griffon 2.x projects. You have the option to initialize a project using `lazybones` however that's not a hard requirement, you can create the project from scratch if you like.

Be warned that IntelliJ has a Griffon plugin. This plugin does not work with Griffon 2.x (http://griffon-framework.org/tutorials/1_getting_started.html#_tutorial_1_4) and its usage is discouraged.

AFAIK there's no `lazybones` support in IntelliJ for project creation.